Wheels won't go on hub despite being correct specc?
I have an Audi A4 B6 1.8T.
Hub size should be 57 milimeters according to the internet: https://www.wheel-size.com/size/audi/a4/b6-2000-2006/eudm/
My current wheels are 7.5Jx16, ET45. My new wheels are 7.5J17, ET43.
However my new wheels won't fit on the hub! It seems like the hub is too big for my wheels. I've tried to measure the diameter of BOTH wheels and it is roughly around 5.5-6.0 centimeters.
What's up? Do I need to like hammer them in place? Or do I need adapters?
TLDR, the hub size of the CAR is too BIG for my NEW wheels. But fits easily on my old ones. Despite the fact that my (innacurate) ruler measurements put them all in the 5.5-6.0 centimeters range, and therefore I think they ought to be 57mm as is spec.

Get an accurate measurement with a caliper. 5.5-6cm doesn't help; the tolerance is far less than a millimeter. A vernier caliper will be accurate enough, and can be picked up for 10-15$.

but why would the wheel be 56mm or 59mm and not 57mm? thats my point. my measurements don't NEED to be accurate, since the idea that somebody made a wheel for an Audi B6 that is 56MM despite knowing the Audi needs 57MM, is ludicrous. you should know that

If you bought wheels advertised as suitable for your car: get a refund. If you just thought "I like these" then caveat emptor. Are they Audi wheels or after market?

Why should i get a refund for wheels that are suitable for my car??
